# Why are my Excel Macros failing every time whenever they attempt to copy or paste a range?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I have tried to do this a thousand different ways with no success. I need a Macro that will comb down a long list of products, copy the line below a product to be inline with it, and then delete the row it copied from.

I haven't reached the "delete" stage of the Macro, because the Macro never makes it past the Range().Copy. I have tried this a number of different ways, including Selecting the range first and specifying the workbook and worksheet (even though there is only one sheet, and I'm only copying within the sheet). I've even tried just recording a Macro, and then playing the Macro back, to see why it works - **but it didn't work!**

My spreadsheet looks something like:

| SKU | Name | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123abc | Pet Rock | 0 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |
|  |  | 0.00 | 123.45 | 0.00 |  |  |  |
| 456efg | Birthday Suit | 2 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |
|  |  | 913.56 | 0 | 456.78 |  |  |  |

Formatted, it would look like this:

| SKU | Name | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123abc | Pet Rock | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0.00 | 123.45 | 0.00 |
| 456efg | Birthday Suit | 2 | 0 | 1 | 913.56 | 0 | 456.78 |

And some code:

```
Sub Format()
    For Each r In Selection.Rows
        If Cells(r, 1).Value = "" Then
            Cells(r, 3).Resize(1, 3).Copy Cells(r, 6) 'have tried this
            Range("C" & r.Row & ":E" & r.Row).Copy Range("F" & r - 1) 'and something like this
            
            'some code to delete here
        End If
        Next r
End Sub
```

I recognise the code might be a little clunky (will clean up once it actually works). Also, other parts might not work that's not my concern, I just need to know why it fails whenever I attempt to copy a range. **Even if that's defined by a recorded Macro.**

I don't know if it matters, but I'm working on a Mac. I've been at this for a while, getting to my wits-end. Please help.

Comment: Do you have 2 rows for all of the products and 3 columns to be pushed up to the right?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes, for every product there are 2 rows. In the actual file I'm formatting, there are 6 columns to be pushed to the right, but it's 6 for every product.

Answer (score 1):

### Move Data: Push Up Right

- Loops through the rows of a selection and when the cell in the first column is blank, two cells to the right of it, if selects 3 consecutive same row cells and copies them 3 cells to the right in the above column and deletes the row.
- For example, if the blank cell is `A5`, it copies `C5:E5` to `F4:H4` and deletes row `5`.
- Note that it is enough to select the first column.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PushUpRight()
    
    Dim r As Long
    With Selection
        For r = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(r, 1).Value = "" Then
                With .Cells(r, 1).Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 3)
                    .Copy .Offset(-1, 3)
                    .EntireRow.Delete
                End With
            End If
        Next r
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the help! Unfortunately, Excel is still getting hung up on the .Copy function. The exact same error is appearing, and when I click "Debug", it highlights line 10: `.Copy .Offset(-1, 3)` as the issue.

Comment: What is the value of `r` at the moment it errors i.e. does it copy anything? Also, if you have 6 columns of data to be copied, you need to replace both 3s with a 6. Also, you didn't share the exact error number and description.

Comment: Feel free to download my file from [my Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1blEQPb4PukjcjFgGLq_wzxTUR5r7nwZ8/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: The value of `r` is correct to the row it's on. I don't know whether it's copying anything - how would I check? The error is thrown before I'm able to log anything. And yes, I corrected the code to show 6. Error code is: 50290, with description: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Check out my file, maybe you can spot a difference so we can fix this.

Comment: Just downloaded and tested yours - it doesn't work with your spreadsheet either? I clicked the button marked "Push" and received the same error code: 50290, but with description: "Method 'ScreenUpdating' of object '_Application' failed"

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I can't help you. I don't know if it's a MAC- or Excel-related issue. Something is definitely wrong.

Comment: Thank you for trying! I did do a fair bit of trouble-shooting before asking the question, so I thought there might be something amiss.

Comment: Let me know how you fixed your issue. I was googling it a bit, but my knowledge about it is minuscule.

Comment: I haven't fixed the issue yet. Perhaps the simplest solution would be to reinstall Excel. I worked around it by opening the spreadsheet in Google Sheets and creating a Macro with Apps Script. It's slower, but it works.